# How to find if the JVM installed on the machine is HotSpot or JRockit on Windows OS

Tags: java, jvm

How to find if the JVM installed on a Windows box is HotSpot or JRockit, or from any other vendor for that matter?

Comment: What do you mean **the** JVM installed?
You can install dozens of different JVMs. And there is no sure way to tell how many and what JVMs are installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use command `java -version` from command prompt, which prints JVM information

Answer (score 14):

Run this command in your terminal

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Also this is a very useful command. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For humans have a look at the various system properties defined.  You most likely want java.vendor.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

For programs it is best to use reflection to test for the JVM specific facility you need instead of relying on arbitrary property values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether the **currently running** JVM is HotSpot or JRockit, check `System.getProperty("java.vm.name")`. For me, it gives `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM` on HotSpot and `Oracle JRockit(R)` on JRockit, although different versions/platforms may give slightly different results, so the most reliable method may be:

```
String jvmName = System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
boolean isHotSpot = jvmName.toUpperCase().indexOf("HOTSPOT") != -1;
boolean isJRockit = jvmName.toUpperCase().indexOf("JROCKIT") != -1;
```

Thorbjørn's suggestion to use `java.vendor` has the problem that the same vendor may produce multiple JVMs; indeed, since Oracle's acquisitions of BEA and Sun, both HotSpot and JRockit now report the same value: `Oracle Corporation`

If you want to find all JVMs installed on a system: the problem with Nambari's answer, to use the command `java -version`, is that the JVM can be installed on a machine yet not be present in the path. For Windows, [scanning the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851778/2147204) could be a better approach.