# Unknown target 'jvm-1.11', Scala Tests build failed

Tags: java, scala, ant

I have a Scala Test Project (Build using ant 1.9) and this project uses java 1.7 to complete the build process. I would like to upgrade the java versions to 1.8, or higher. For that I downloaded jdk-11.0.10 and updated the build.xml file like:

```
<!-- scalac target="jvm-1.6"-->//This was before my update
<scalac target="jvm-1.11"
                destdir="${project.subdir.classes}"
                deprecation="yes"
                unchecked="yes">
            <src path="${project.rootdir.source}/scala"/>
            <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
        </scalac>
```

I also updated the new java path in the buildenv.properties file. When I try to build the Scala source code then it throws the following error

Unknow target 'jvm-1.11'

I am not using any IDE. Can anyone please suggest me on updating the java in Scala Project. Thanks

Comment: Which is your **Scala** version? If it is an older one it will not support **Java** `11` check [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html). - BTW, why **ant**?

Comment: Thank you Luis. it is a legacy project that's why ant. Unfortunately, the project is using Scala-lang-2.10.0 and scalatest-1.9.1. Now I think I have to upgrade Scala first

Comment: Yes it would be good to at least use **Scala** `2.12` which requires a minimum version of **Java** `8` and should work with **Java** `11` out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I am already trying that. Is there any simple way to do that? As it is ant build so the only things I have is source code and build file. I was thinking of using Eclipse Scala Plugin and importing the project using build.xml.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with a simple way? Like how to edit the code? Yeah, an IDE like **IntelliJ** is probably a good idea, but not sure if it recognizes **ant** builds. - My advice would be, upgrade one major version at a time, like first upgrade to the latest `2.10` version and ensure there are no warnings. Then upgrade to `2.11.0` and fix warnings, then try to upgrade libraries _(in case you didn't have to already)_ fix warnings / errors, then upgrade to the latest `2.11` release and repeat until you are in the latest `2.12` release and hopefully in the latest release of your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I will try this way. Thanks again

Comment: Do you try to chanhe from jvm-1.11 to jvm-11?

Comment: Hello Dmitri, yes it would work. Please see the answer below for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the jvm version. As explained by many other answers to find the jvm version is to use

```
java -version
```

the above command does not provide you the jvm version, it provides java version and some other info. The solution I found was in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56211337/8479386). To find the jvm version use the following command

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

This will output something like following screenshot with lots of other info as well

[image]

To find jvm version find the string

> java.vm.specification.version

and it would be the jvm version.