# Getting the path to Java in a Java program

Tags: java

Was reading this question: [Execute .jar file from a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4936266/555690) and the answer tells you to use a `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/java", "-jar", "your.jar");
```

How do I find out the `/path/to/java` using code? Of course I could look up `java` in my machine, but an end-user may not necessarily have Java installed in the same place as I do...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493856/how-to-programatically-get-all-java-jvm-installed-not-default-one-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.getProperty("java.home")`.