# Can I programmatically detect if Corretto Java is installed and which version?

Tags: corretto

Amazon Corretto is a replacement to Oracle JRE/JDK.

Is there a way to detect if Corretto is installed (on windows machine) programmatically and if installed - which version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the Default installed JDK is Amazon Corretto by checking the `JAVA_HOME` path, and if it's you can get the version from the path for example

```java
String javaHomePath = System.getProperty("java.home");
if (javaHomePath.contains("corretto")) {
            
}
```

Or you check if it installed but not default by checking the list of files in the `JAVA_HOME` parent directory for example

```java
File file = new File(javaHomePath);
File[] jvmFiles = file.getParentFile().listFiles();
for (File jvmFile : jvmFiles) {
    if (jvmFile.getPath().contains("corretto")) {
        String amazonCorrettoPath = jvmFile.getPath();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can install corretto without JAVA_HOME as well. isn't there a way to check in registry ?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/11851778/7227834